# How to send http request using c# to get data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, xamarin

I have a Xamarin app.

I would like to connect my app to my local MySQL database.

I would like to pull some information from the MySql table and show in my app.

After some research; I have concluded to use REST API to establish the connection with app and MySQL.

So I started to work on the Http Request.

Now, I have a website which uses the MySQL database. I would like to send HTTP request to my website page and get data and show in table/list.

I have started but not sure what I am doing.

**This is c# page.**

```
   protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            string html = string.Empty;
            string url = @"https://mywebsite/test.php";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response =  client.GetAsync(url);


        }
```

**This is test.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


            $prepare_query = "SELECT * from test;";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli_scs, $prepare_query);

           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
             echo $row['name'];
             echo "<br>";

                  }
?>
```

I am not sure whether I am doing this right.

Can somebody help me to set up the write HTTP request and what code I need on test.php file.

Finally, How I can display the result in the app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Firstly, I'd use .NET WebAPI rather than PHP: you're less likely to introduce inconsistencies if you stick with the same platform as much as possible. Second, instead of returning HTML, why not return JSON and parse it?

Comment: Thanks @Jon Story. That's what I needed help; The correct way to send Http request and returning JSON and parsing it.

Comment: Despite what @JonStory says there is no reason your backend has to use the same platform as your client.  That said, all the individual pieces you need - making a request, returning JSON, consuming JSON, etc - are well documented on SO and elsewhere on the web.  Please try doing some research, and then if you have a specific question about a specific part of the process, ask it.  But asking us to write all of the code for you is beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: There's no reason it HAS to, but it can make life a lot easier when new to the field as OP appears to be